# How to connect Prometheus in Docker to a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus

I am referring to this link (https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus) to install Prometheus in Docker version into a Ubuntu server (server-1)

I also have a Kubernetes cluster (bare-metal) running in another Ubuntu server (server-2). In this Kubernetes cluster, I have some sample apps being deployed.

I know normally people will deploy Prometheus to the same Kubernetes cluster.

But now, I want to use this Prometheus in server-1 to monitor the apps in Kubernetes cluster in server-2. How to achieve this? Is there any setting/ configuration I have to do to achieve the monitoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both servers can access each other, you will need to configure the prometheus on server-2 to [scrape the targets](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) running on server-1, which in turn will have to expose their `/metrics` path in a way that server-2 can access (via ingress is the most popular choice).

Comment: Sure thing, if this is the right answer to your question, please accept it as the correct one.